# How many candies are in the jar?

Tags: impossible-test-2

[image]

This question is asking how much candy is in the jar. This is based on a previous question where it asks you to take a candy.[image]

I don't want to mess up, and I think there is more than twenty. I don't know if I miscounted, but how much candies are in the jar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Games Dreams](http://gamesdreams.com/showthread.php?34281-The-Impossible-Test-2-How-many-candies-were-in-the-jar-Q18), there are 26 candies in the jar.